# How to get the offset of a member at compile time when it's private?

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a linked list class which uses a macro to get the offset of the node member within the object. Setting aside the question of whether offsetof() is guaranteed to work for all data types, can anyone think of a way to get this offset at compile time and still allow the data member to be private? I've spent some time getting nowhere with template and studied the boost::instrusive source code, but they seem to get the offset at runtime (although I'm not sure, the code is quite hard to navigate) which isn't acceptable in this case.

I've experimented with friend / template helper classes but just can't see a way to do it.

An alternative would be to specify the child node in the list template declaration somehow and use offsetof() in getnode(), but I can't work out how that's done, my template-fu is not strong enough. Can it be done with the pointer-to-member template parameter type?

This illustrates the problem, it's not supposed to compile...

```
// mylist.h

#include <cstddef>

struct node
{
    node *prev;
    node *next;
};

template <typename T, size_t o> struct list
{
    static node *getnode(T *obj)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<node *>(reinterpret_cast<char *>(obj) + o);
    }

    node root;

    list()
    {
        root.next = root.prev = &root;
    }

    void addtail(T *object)
    {
        node *n = getnode(object);
        n->prev = root.prev;
        n->next = &root;
        root.prev->next = n;
        root.prev = n;
    }

    // etc...
}

#define linked_list(str, node) list<name, offsetof(str, node)>

// test.cpp

struct foo
{
    int i;

private:
    node m_node;
};

linked_list(foo, m_node) mylist;    // error, m_node is private...
```

Comment: This particular wheel is already invented, see `boost::intrusive::list`.

Comment: Yes, I've been studying it intently. My aim is to learn, but I'm not yet able to understand the source code - the template mangling is beyond me, currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `reinterpret_cast` is a red-herring already, and of course `offsetof` as well.

Have you considered:

```
class Node {
    template <typename T> friend class List;
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    Node* next = nullptr;
}; // class Node

template <typename T>
class List {
public:
    void push_back(T& object)
    {
        Node& n = getnode(object);
        n.prev = root.prev;
        n.next = &root;
        root.prev->next = &n;
        root.prev = &n;
    }
private:
    Node root;
}; // class List
```

Simple, isn't it ? And now:

```
class Foo {
public:
    friend Node& getnode(Foo& foo) { return foo.node; }

private:
    int payload;
    Node node;
}; // class Foo
```

It compiles, respecting privacy [see here](https://ideone.com/vQPE52), but crashes (because `push_back` is wrong, I'll let you work on this).

---

And here is an implementation for multiple nodes within a given object:

```
class Node {
    template <typename, size_t> friend class List;
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    Node* next = nullptr;
}; // class Node

template <typename T, size_t Index>
class List {
public:
    void push_back(T& object)
    {
        Node& n = getnode(object, std::integral_constant<size_t, Index>{});
        n.prev = root.prev;
        n.next = &root;
        root.prev->next = &n;
        root.prev = &n;
    }
private:
    Node root;
}; // class List
```

With the user class:

```
class Foo {
public:
    friend Node& getnode(Foo& foo, std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>) {
        return foo.node;
    }

explicit Foo(int p = 0): payload(p) {}
private:
    int payload;
    Node node;
}; // class Foo
```

Comment: I need to specify the node member (data or function) in the list template so I can add objects to more than one list - can this method be modified to allow that? If so, we might have a winner...

Comment: @CharlieSkilbeck: sure, it's trivial.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on with the call to getnode() in the List class - the empty braces, what's going on there?

Comment: I can't get this to compile if I have a List instance declared as 'List<Foo, 0> mylist' - I removed the {} from the call to getnode (was this a typo?) but now I get 'illegal use of this type as an expression' in the call to getnode.

Comment: @CharlieSkilbeck: `{}` is C++11 notation to call the default constructor, there are a few other C++11 things too. [Here is a C++03 version](https://ideone.com/hWNumf)

Comment: Gotcha, this is good - it doesn't allow the client to specify the name of the list node but I can live with that, thanks!

Comment: Ah, one small problem. I'm not able to get the remove() working right, because it's a circular list, so there's no way to know if the next, prev pointers are pointing at a Foo or a simple Node. Back to the drawing board?

Comment: @CharlieSkilbeck: no, it should be working. `next` and `prev` are always pointing at a `Node` (they are `Node*`), what you don't know is whether this `Node` is within a `Foo` or is the `root` itself, but you can compare `prev` (or `next`) with `&root` to know that.

Comment: Yes, but then it's not branchless, which is a shame, do you think there's a way? The whole point of it being circular is to remove branches...

Comment: @CharlieSkilbeck: I would need more details on the specific operations, and specifically whether you are trying to remove a specific `Foo`, by position or by predicate. You might consider asking a new question so you can provide the code you have at the moment, if you do feel free to add a comment here with the url to the new question and I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a requirement that you have to design the list the way you do? Because it's not the common way to handle lists.

The common way is to have a private node structure that contains the actual data. Something like

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
    struct node
    {
        node* next;
        node* prev;
        T     data;  // Data store in the node
    }

    node* list;  // The actual list

public:
    // ...

    void AddHead(const T& data)
    {
        node* n = new node;
        n->data = data;

        // ...
    }

    // ...
};
```

Use it like this:

```
struct foo
{
    int i;
};

List<foo> myList;

foo myFoo;
myList.AddHead(myFoo);
```

With this design, you don't even need structures to store primitive types such as `int`:

```
List<int> myIntegerList;
myList.AddHead(5);
```

Comment: From what he said he does so because he's designing an "intrusive container" to avoid the overhead of the extra data structure.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work - I would use a std::list of pointers if this was an option.

Comment: @charlieskikbeck 'this won't work' conveys little information.  Can you explain **why** it won't work?

Comment: @MatteoItalia There are no "extra" data structures in my design compared to the OPs, the OP still have a `node` structure, just like me. The difference is that instead of making every external data structure contain the node data, my design keeps the data in the node instead. This makes the list more self-contained, and also means that the list can contain trivial data-structures or even primitive types such as `int`.

Comment: But I need an object to be a member of more than one list, which in this case would mean storing a list of pointers to the objects which would cause a blizzard of tiny node allocations (which is the thing I need to prevent).

Comment: @CharlieSkilbeck Maybe you could edit your question to include a use-case and a list of requirements? Maybe explaining *why* you can't have allocations like in my design? Have you thought about using a [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) with a custom allocator to prevent these small allocations?

Comment: intrusive lists and the rationale behind them are fairly well understood, I don't think they need an explanation

Comment: @CharlieSkilbeck Oh and by the way, having the `node` structure embedded into the actual data structure will not allow you to put the node in multiple lists, only one single list. Adding the structure to another list will overwrite the `node` data.

Comment: That's why we need to specify the node member name in the list template, so we can have more than one node in an object